# with less college education

Tags: meaning-in-context, error

Should the boldfaced phrase in the following have been "with less than college education and lower income"?

> The shift in sentiment in the NY Fed survey was driven by families **with less college education** and lower income. About one in three (34%) of those surveyed who make less than $60,000 think they will eventually own a home. That’s down from 46% in 2020. Likewise, 34% of those with less than a bachelor’s degree expect to own a home, down from 46% two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  It probably means "Less than the average amount of college education".

A family can have more education or less.

I don't know what the average amount of college education is in the US now, but a family with two wage earners, both of whom have Masters degrees would have more than an average amount of college education.

On the other hand, a family in which only one adult has an associate (2 year) degree, and the other didn't go to college at all would have less college education.

So the shift in sentiment was driven not (only) by those with no college education, but also those will less education, such as associate degrees.

Comment: I mostly agree with you except that I see it more as "the number/percentage of family members with college education" than "the average amount of college education". Hence: families with less college education = families with a lower number of college graduates. But I am probably nitpicking. It'll boil down to about the same thing,

Answer (score 0):

No it should not have been.

> driven by families with less college education and lower income

The above is perfectly fine, as it reveals how families have *less* college education, or even no education possibly. To have *less than* only works with e.g. the "less than **a** bachelor's degree" mentioned in the text as well, as it depicts how people have a associate's degree are now less likely to own a home.

If you say *less than **a** college education*, you are implying the person has something less than a college education, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I agree that the "less college education" in the original text is fine, but I'm not sure why you think "something less than a college education" doesn't make sense.  Someone who only graduated high school, or didn't graduate high school, could be said to have "less than a college education".

Comment: Hmm ok I never thought about that thanks!